# PHP Lighthouse simple custom directory for rounding a field

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I want to create a simple GrapQL directive `@round` for rounding floats to a set precision.

I managed to get it working, but the solution troubles me and I feel that I did some thing wrong.

This is my simple type, where on `sum` field I use `@round` directive.

```
type StatsPriceOutput {
    count: Int!
    sum: Float! @round(precision: 4)
}
```

The class of `RoundDirective`:

```
final class RoundDirective extends BaseDirective implements FieldResolver
{
    public static function definition(): string {
        return /** @lang GraphQL */ <<<'GRAPHQL'
directive @round(precision: Int = 2) on FIELD_DEFINITION
GRAPHQL;
    }

    public function resolveField(FieldValue $fieldValue): FieldValue {
        $fieldValue->setResolver(function ($value) use ($fieldValue) { // $value returns both fields: count and sum. Expecting only sum
            $fieldName = $fieldValue->getFieldName();
            $precision = $this->directiveArgValue('precision', 2);
            return round($value[$fieldName], $precision);
        });
        return $fieldValue;
    }
}
```

I feel that I'm doing something wrong, because I clearly set `@round` directive on `sum` field, but in the `$fieldValue->setResolver` the `$value` returns array of both fields `['count' => 'some value', 'sum' => 'some other value']`.

Dump of the `$value` variable:

[image: Dump of the $value variable]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

setResolver accept a resolver closure that have following signature :

```
function ($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo)
```

To achieve what you want, it is simpler to use a FieldMiddleware.

The following implementation assumes you are on Lighthouse 6.x, syntax using Lighthouse 5 is a bit different, check documentation for appropriate version: https://lighthouse-php.com/master/custom-directives/getting-started.html#directive-interfaces

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\GraphQL\Directives;

use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Execution\ResolveInfo;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Directives\BaseDirective;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Values\FieldValue;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\FieldMiddleware;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext;

final class RoundDirective extends BaseDirective implements FieldMiddleware
{
    public static function definition(): string {
        return 'directive @round(precision: Int! = 2) on FIELD_DEFINITION';
    }

    /**
     * Wrap around the final field resolver.
     */
    public function handleField(FieldValue $fieldValue): void
    {
        $fieldValue->wrapResolver(fn (callable $resolver) => 
            fn (mixed $root, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $info) => round(
                $resolver($root, $args, $context, $info),
                $this->directiveArgValue('precision', 2),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```